# Karma webpack - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, ant, webpack, karma-runner

4 12 2016 21:13:44.714:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
04 12 2016 21:13:45.328:INFO [Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#yBiSlDbPdR0p0hZyAAAA with id 95065212
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  at config/karma.entry.js

I run npm test in the terminal window and get the error above.

I can get chrome to launch ...

Webpack I is working as I can run an ANT build that calls NPM and it creates and deploys a working war.

I just cannot get Karma to play nice.  I have been trying many fixes based on internet searches with no luck, I am new to all of this.

Can anyone help?  Using angular2 , angular cli

I have pushed all my files to git..

Using INtellij ultimate as my IDE

https://github.complinet.com/barbara-switzer/GrcWorkFlow

Comment: can you show your karma.config.js

Comment: All my code is at the following link: https://github.com/brs224/angularTest (posted incorrect link earlier) karma config is in the conf directory

Comment: try adding `requirejs` in framework

Comment: I added reuirejs to frameworks in my Karma config, now I get:  Uncaught Error: Module name "es6-shim" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at node_modules/requirejs/require.js:143

Comment: In `config/karma.conf.js`, you should have `'./config/karma.entry.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']` for  preprocessors.

Comment: Connected on socket /#lUzW_3G1DTUvEg54AAAA with id 2253338
07 12 2016 14:46:09.679:WARN [web-server]: 404: /%3Cmain%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%7B%7Btitle%7D%7D%0D%0A%3C/h1%3E%0D%0A%3Csample1%3E%3C/sample1%3E%0D%0A%3C/div%3E%0D%0A%3C/main%3E%0D
%0A
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) App: HelloWorld should create the app FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at webpack:///web/app/app.component.spec.ts:22:20 <- config/karma.entry.js:44257:26

Comment: Latest code is available at: https://github.com/brs224/angularTest3

Comment: Made some progress, now getting 'Unhandled Promise rejection', Template parse errors, sample1 is not a known component

Comment: Now getting..   08 12 2016 10:50:16.733:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#PAI59ntU7ecV8ZIAAAAA with id 13346718
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) App: HelloWorld should create the app FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.

Comment: Do you remember what the reason was for the 'require is not defined'?